# JavaFX & FXML black screen on minimizing

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx, jira, java-8

I believe that I have found a bug with Java 1.8, but I am not 100% sure. I created an issue on Jira ([RT-36853](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-36853)), just in case this turns out to be a bug. Can someone please confirm this is a bug, versus something that I could be coding incorrectly.

If I create a JavaFX or FXML application using NetBeans 8.0 & JDK 1.8, the application will show a blank black screen when restoring the window after it has been minimized. If I create the same application with JDK 1.7 I do not get the same issue.

The code that was used in the program is the standard code that NetBeans 8.0 generates when creating a new application.

Comment: SO is not an appropriate place for posting bug reports. If you do wish to make a [PSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_service_announcement) on SO, make sure it is *still* framed in terms of a question. Then let the *answers* be "there is a bug", if indeed there is one. To fulfill the desire to write a statement/article/solution, consider a blog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to confirm that it was a bug, and you will run into it if you are using JDK 8u05 (which at this time comes standard with the development kit from Oracle) and minimize using the task bar icon on Windows 7 (unsure of other platforms). This has been repaired as of JDK 8u20 [available here](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html).